# Indefinite integral of nested trig functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I tried vainly to integrate nested trig functions like

```
Integrate[Sin[Cos[x]], x]
```

*Mathematica* does not find a solution. At first I thought there was no solution, but MatLab does find it. Now I think that perhaps `Cos[x]` is not a valid argument for `Sin[]`, but I don't know how to make it valid.

By the way, the actual integral I want to do is:

```
Integrate[Integrate[Sin[x]*(Sin[-a*Sin[x]-b*Sin[x]*Sin[y] - c*Cos[x]])^2, x], y]
```

With $a, b, c$ constants.

I'm using *Mathematica* 9.

Comment: What results does Matlab return?

Comment: Have a look here [Integrals That Can and Cannot Be Done](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegralsThatCanAndCannotBeDone.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link Louis, it turns out it's not integrable. MarcoB, I do not have MatLab, I asked a friend of mine to do the integral and she told me MatLab did it, and I trusted her, but no, I checked with other people and no, MatLab does not integrate it either.

Comment: Matlab may have done it numerically....

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can get a symbolic result of sorts for `Integrate[Sin[Sin[x]], x]`, in terms of a rapidly convergent infinite series:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As Louis [points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109188/indefinite-integral-of-nested-trig-functions#comment295535_109188), the related integral `Integrate[Sin[Sin[x]], x]` cannot be done by *Mathematica* (in finite terms) according to the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegralsThatCanAndCannotBeDone.html).

First expand the `Sin[]` in `Integrate[Sin[Cos[x]], x]` in its Taylor series:

```
intcoeffs = 
  TrigExpand@
     Integrate[Table[SeriesCoefficient[Sin[u], {u, 0, n}] Cos[x]^n,
       {n, 1, 51, 2}], x] /. Cos[x]^n_ :> (1 - Sin[x]^2)^(n/2) // 
   Expand;
(*
  {  Sin[x],
   -(Sin[x]/6) +    Sin[x]^3/18, 
     Sin[x]/120 -   Sin[x]^3/180 +  Sin[x]^5/600,
   -(Sin[x]/5040) + Sin[x]^3/5040 - Sin[x]^5/8400 + Sin[x]^7/35280,
   ...}
*)
```

There is a pattern to the coefficients of `Sin[k x]`.  If this were math.SE, we might want a proof. But on Mathematica.SE, we have ***[`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)***!

```
FindSequenceFunction@Coefficient[intcoeffs, Sin[x]]
(*  ((-1)^(1 + #1) 4^(1 - #1))/(Pochhammer[1, -1 + #1] Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + #1]) &  *)
```

Let's get a few more:

```
sincoeffs = Table[FindSequenceFunction@Coefficient[intcoeffs, Sin[x]^n], {n, 1, 19, 2}];
```

The `Pochhammer` symbols have the "obvious" pattern

```
Pochhammer[1, -k + n] Pochhammer[k + 1/2, -k + n]
```

The rest has the pattern

```
FindSequenceFunction[
 Block[{Pochhammer = 1 &}, (4)^n*Through[sincoeffs[n]]/(-1)^n]
 ]
(*  (4 (-1)^#1)/(Pochhammer[1, -1 + #1] Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + #1] (-1 + 2 #1)) &  *)
```

Pasting it all together yields

```
coeffFN = (4^(1 - #2) (-1)^(#1 - #2)) /
  (Pochhammer[1, -1 + #1] Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + #1] *
   Pochhammer[1, -#1 + #2] Pochhammer[#1 + 1/2, -#1 + #2] (-1 + 2 #1)) // 
      FullSimplify // Evaluate // Function
(*
((-1)^(#1 - #2) 2^(1 - 2 #2) Sqrt[π]) /
  (Gamma[#1] Gamma[1/2 + #2] Gamma[1 - #1 + #2] (-1 + 2 #1)) &
*)
```

Check with the above coefficients:

```
Table[Sum[coeffFN[k, n] Sin[x]^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, 4}]
(*
  { Sin[x],
   -(Sin[x]/6) +    Sin[x]^3/18, 
     Sin[x]/120 -   Sin[x]^3/180 +  Sin[x]^5/600,
   -(Sin[x]/5040) + Sin[x]^3/5040 - Sin[x]^5/8400 + Sin[x]^7/35280}
*)
```

Thus the integral is given by

```
Sum[coeffFN[k, n] Sin[x]^(2 k - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}, {k, 1, n}]
```

Check numerically (recall that the precision goal is half `WorkingPrecision`; the constant of integration turns out to be zero):

```
nint = NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
(*
  0.73864299803689018380009029058522
*)

Sum[testfn[k, n] Sin[1.`32]^(2 k - 1), {n, 1, 9}, {k, 1, n}]
(% - nint)/nint
(*
  0.73864299803689018612760424278533
  3.1510675094545*10^-18
*)
```

Somewhat faster, too:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 32] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Sum[testfn[k, n] Sin[1.`32]^(2 k - 1), {n, 1, 9}, {k, 1, n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*
  0.005813
  0.001727
*)
```